# Keep a Bitmap on top at literally all times

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a timer event which seems to once in a while call itself before the `ENTER_FRAME` event handler which I made to force a `Bitmap` object to be top-most at all times by adding itself to the stage again.

The timer event fires every 50 milliseconds.

I tried setting the priority of the `ENTER_FRAME` event to 1, which reduced the ugly flickering, but did not remove it.

How can I force this `Bitmap` object to be top-most at literally all times with no flickering whatsoever?

Comment: A quick side comment. You should consider not using a Timer, and driving all your logic out of your frame handler. The reason is that whatever you're doing in that Timer only gets painted to the screen once per frame anyway, so all the Timer event does is introduce issues when you happen to get more than one timer per frame, or vice versa. It's better to do the logic once per frame, and adjust the logic based on how many miliseconds have elapsed since the last frame if you need something to be time-based rather than frame-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two container MovieClips at the root of your application. Put all of your other display objects in the lower one and the Bitmap in the higher one. It saves you having to run a loop at all.

Alternatively, whenever you add something to the stage, instead of using addChild, use `addChildAt(newChild,getChildIndex(bitmap)-1);`

Comment: Well that was oddly effective, your first solution worked and was fairly easy to implement. Thanks for ending my headache, I'll accept when the time lets me.